# Reference for proof of Landau's prime ideal theorem (English)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and $\pi_K(x)$ be the number of prime ideals in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ with norm $\le x$. In 1903, Landau showed that
$$\pi_K(x)=Li(x)+O_K(x\exp(-c_K\sqrt{\log x}))$$
for some positive $c_K$ dependent only on $K$. The original paper (*Neuer Beweis des Primzahlsatzes und Beweis des Primidealsatzes*) is in German and I have been unable to find an account in English.

Cojocaru and Murty quote the result in their book *An introduction to sieve methods and their applications* but don't provide a reference. Apparently Montgomery and Vaughan quote the result in their book *Multiplicative number theory I. Classical theory.* (pp. 266-268), however I have yet to access it.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Do you need a reference, or are you interested in how the proof goes? If the latter, it's quite similar to Landau's proof of the ordinary PNT, and I could post an outline describing the proof.

Comment: Chapter 6 of Iwaniec & Kowalski's Analytic Number Theory has the result. They work quite generally at first and then specialize to Dedekind zeta functions.

Comment: (I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment, so I'll post this as a reply) Small correction to @eloiprime's reply: This is in chap 5 of Iwaniec-Kowalski, specifically Theorem 5.13.